# How can I set up a database schema where there are two concurrent many-many relationships?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, schema, denormalization

I need a table to hold downtime, basically a downtime **event** contains the following info:
EVENT_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, SERVICES, CAUSES
The main issue is that I don't know how to set this up because I don't want to end up with a mess like this:

```
ID  |  EVENT_ID  |  START_TIME  |  END_TIME  | SERVICES  |  CAUSES
01          455       12:00          12:30      FINANCE     NETWORK
02          455       12:00          12:30      ADVANCE     NETWORK
...
13          455       12:00          12:30      REFRESH     DATABASE
```

Basically...for a single outage, I would have many many entries in the table, since if there are multiple services/causes, the table would in effect hold all combinations.

Is there a more efficient way of organizing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes - normalize a little:

```
EVENT
------
event_id
start_tm
end_tm
description

EVENT_SERVICE
-------------
event_id
service_id
employee_id 
start_tm
end_tm
(other info as needed)

SERVICE
---------
service_id
description

CAUSE
-------
cause_id
description

EVENT_CAUSE
-----------
event_id
cause_id
```

*edited* to reflect ypercubes comment with a separate SERVICE table

Comment: Isn't there a `SERVICE` table missing?

Comment: Hmm, but how are those linked together? For example, how is the main EVENT table linked to the list of services and causes? Also EVENT_CAUSE table would be pretty repetitive because it would list several causes for a single event ID?

Comment: @ypercube - yes IF the services were repeatable... then the pattern would be just the same (as you know) as the EVENT

Comment: @antonpug the main event gets a unique event_id as a Primary Key, then in the EVENT_SERVICE, you refer to that event_id as a Foreign Key - that allows many services to be performed on each event.Similar for the CAUSE(s).